# .htaccess 301 redirect old domain sub-folder without root domain access to new domain root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to move my website from a domain and server where I am just a user to a domain that I control.

I want to redirect every request at http://www.olddomain.com/~username/ to http://www.newdomain.com/ - and I only have access to ~username on the server.

Everything I try ends up at http://www.newdomain.com/~username/

1)

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.newdomain.com/
```

2)

```
Redirect 301 /~username/ http://www.newdomain.com/
```

3)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^~username/(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

4)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~username/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

I would probably prefer to redirect everything to just http://www.newdomain.com/index.html, but for the sake of completeness please also show how to redirect to a matching URL on the new server.

Apache mod_rewrite docs:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: That is weird. Option 3 and 4 should definitely work. Do you empty your browser cache every time you make a change? Redirects *are* cached and you need to be very careful, otherwise you could think it doesn't work while it's actually just a cache issue.

Comment: Yeah, that did it.  Thanks a lot.  Firefox -> Clear Recent History... -> Last Two Hours

Answer (score 0):

Per @Capsule's comment, I just needed to clear the cache in my browser.  Refreshing the page / revisiting the old domain is not sufficient.

Firefox -> History -> Clear Recent History... -> Last Hour